# “got me feeling” or “gives me” , which one seems grammatically correct?

Tags: phrase-request

when a picture gives you 2016 vibes, how do you say it in a sentence? Is it accurate to say “This picture got me feeling 2016 vibes” , or any other way to say this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a silly question - but what was wrong with the expression that you used naturally - that "the picture *gives me* (or *gave me*) 2016 vibes" it sounds more natural than the two other options you suggest. Otherwise, I would suggest something like "the picture resonated 2016" or "the picture evoked 2016".

Comment: What exactly are "2016 vibes"?

Comment: @Michael Harvey - I assumed that it meant that it recreated the feeling of being back in time in 2016 as opposed to 2,016 vibrations - but I was just feeling the vibe :)

Comment: I got that. I can imagine a 1980s vibe, or a 1970s vibe (I'm that old) but a _2016_ vibe?

Comment: @Michael Harvey as my 62nd birthday is on Monday, I have to admit to finding it hard to differentiate between decades, let alone years :) - but the way that fashions change so fast, these days, maybe someone who is very fashion aware might see the clothes in a two-year old picture as dated... [she said, adjusting her maxi skirt and wondering where her bell bottoms had gone...]

Answer (score -1):

You could use the word "**imbued**" or one of its **synonyms**. It can be used to describe conveying strong/nostalgic feeling, memory, or emotions.

> This picture ***imbues*** me with "2016" vibrations.
>
> This picture ***fills*** me with "2016" vibrations.
>
> This picture ***permeates*** (me) with "2016" vibrations.
>
> This picture ***conveys*** (to me) "2016" vibrations.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/imbue

https://www.freethesaurus.com/imbue